# Get db from current user firestore query kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin

whats up?
I have an app that displays a list of items on Firestore using Kotlin and RecyclerView (from FirebaseUI api).

The DB is structured like this:

```
Users/userID/document_month_year
```

I need to query the data from the current user.
Each user has his own document_month_year document.
I read a lot of posts here, but each one tell one thing.. there´s no consense and nothing seems to work.

This query just sends me all documents from all users, how can I fix this?

```
private val queryFilteredByPaidStatus = db.collectionGroup(collectionName).whereEqualTo("users", userId)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this is an important question, here is the awnser that I

```
private val queryTest = db.document("users/"+userId).collection(collectionName)

    fun getData() : FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Expense> {
     return FirestoreRecyclerOptions
        .Builder<Expense>()
        .setQuery(queryTest, Expense::class.java)
        .build()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate collection for documents to be read i.e month_year and for each document, add a field inside it which tells you the uid of the authenticated user, to which the document belongs to. Now you can query the collection like:

```
firestoreDB.collections("month_year").whereEqualTo("uid",auth.currentUser.uid)
```